# return index of element in form

Tags: html, vba

This is probably easy but I can't manage to get the index of a table in the form as you can see in

[image: this picture].

I have selected the table I want the index from the following way :

```
IEDoc.querySelectorAll("td[width='100'][class='ListMainCent'][rowSpan='1'][colSpan='1']")(2).ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode
```

So as you can see, I selected it from one of its items.

So my question is, how can i gain the index position of this table in the form ?

Comment: You could use your selector to add a name or id to the table, then iterate the top level tables in the form until the table with name/id is found and you would have your index. Be sure to check the overhead of such a process.

Comment: Thanks dude ! works perfectly !!

Comment: I added the process as an answer. Please check it as correct if you would!   Glad it worked for you (sometimes its the little things, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use your selector to add a name or id to the table.
2. Iterate the top level tables in the form until the table with name/id is found.

   You now have your index.

   Be sure to check the overhead of such a process.

Comment: I managed to do this except for the last step. Once I have set an ID to the table I want the index from, how do I actually return the index from this table in the whole collection ? What I want to be returned is "27" in the case of the highlighted table

Comment: if you are iterating your tables using a 'for' loop, the counting variable should start at zero and end at the iteration when the table is found. The counter number +1 is the top level table number. In your example I count only 23 top level tables in the form... are you looking at something else?